# Eslint not working in Sublime Text 3 or in the terminal

Tags: sublimetext3, eslint

Eslint is not working in my Sublime Text 3 or in the terminal.

I followed the instructions that are in this README.

https://github.com/roadhump/SublimeLinter-eslint

I first installed eslint globally in my terminal by entering

```
npm install -g eslint
```

When I type eslint -v in my terminal, I get

```
v4.5.0
```

I installed SublimeLinter-contrib-eslint through Package Control.

When I type in my terminal

```
hash -r
which eslint
```

It gives me

```
/usr/local/bin/eslint
```

In my Sublime console it says eslint cannot find my configuration files. I ran

```
eslint --init
```

this is the info I received in my console

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'eslint' is not defined
```

Can someone explain to me what this means and how I can fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing the Sublime Text console with a [terminal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) (also sometimes referred to as console)

> Sublime Text exposes its internals via an Application Programming Interface (API) that programmers can interact with using the Python programming language. An embedded Python interpreter is included in the editor. The embedded interpreter is useful to inspect the editor’s settings and to quickly test API calls while developing plugins.

So, you can only run Python commands and Python methods exposed by Sublime Text in its console. The plugin for `eslint` is available through the command palette.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you for your response.